# Compiling Maxcoin and its clone cryptos throw an error

Tags: windows, litecoin-qt, maxcoin

I compiled Bitcoin, Dogecoin, and many other pow/pos cryptocurrencies without a problem. I usually compile daemon and then windows-qt wallet using qt 5.2.

But maxcoin and its clones like Helixcoin and galleoncoin always throw this particular error once I have compiled and run on windows 8. QT4.8.5

```
the procedure entry point memmove s could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll
```

coin daemon compiles and runs without a problem. And I downloaded their pre compiled windows-qt wallets from official websites and they work fine.

this is my config for compilation

```
BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX=-mgw48-mt-s-1_50 
BOOST_INCLUDE_PATH=C:/boost-1.50.0-mgw
BOOST_LIB_PATH=C:/boost-1.50.0-mgw/stage/lib
BDB_INCLUDE_PATH=C:/db-4.8.30.NC-mgw/build_unix
BDB_LIB_PATH=C:/db-4.8.30.NC-mgw/build_unix
OPENSSL_INCLUDE_PATH=C:/openssl-1.0.1c-mgw/include
OPENSSL_LIB_PATH=C:/openssl-1.0.1c-mgw
MINIUPNPC_INCLUDE_PATH=C:/
MINIUPNPC_LIB_PATH=C:/miniupnpc-1.6-mgw
QT4.8.5
```

This is the source I am working on
    https://github.com/HelixCoin/

I have already looked through all of the files and I do not understand the cause of this error. And there is not much help on internet.

Comment: You might want to try updating msvcrt.dll, as it seems that your version is lacking a function that Maxcoin wants to use. – This came up in a websearch, but it is for WindowsXP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324762/en

Comment: @Murch Hi, I appreciate your comment. But those coins work fine which are pre compiled by devs. And can you tell me where do I obtain the msvcrt.dll which would be best for maxcoin? I cant find it anywhere.

Comment: The precompiled version probably includes the dependencies, which would be why it only occurs for the self-compiled.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/68006-63-reinstall-msvcrt-library

Comment: oh, that makes sense. Do you know how to include the dll files in the new compilation. What I mean is there is nothing in the files that could give me an idea of how to include the missing dlls in the qmake or makefile on windows. Can you point me to the right direction. Thank you!

Edit: let me check that out.

Comment: My intuition would be that after installing the C++ package, it should be found automatically, as the `msvcrt.dll` would just be replaced.

Comment: @Murch that would force end user to install C++ which I want to not be necessary to make it easier for them.

Comment: installed vcredist_x86.exe. Unfortunately, it does not help

Comment: nothing worked. I going to use a source which is compatible with qt 5.2.0 and then will update here.

Comment: Update: I used another source with worked with qt 5.2.0. And it works fine. I still don't get what is the problem with qt 4.8.5. It has msvcrt.dll and/or other libs missing.

Comment: Cool! It would be nice if you could briefly explain what you did and what finally worked for you in an answer to your own question, making available your research for others to find here. :)

Comment: okay, going to post a short answer. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally decided to give up trying to use qt 4.8.5 and helixcoin and galleoncoin github sources. And used qt 5.2.0 with slothcoin source from github. Which worked fine. And qt wallet started without a problem. Though I still dont understand why was qt 4.8.5 not including the msrvct.dll file. maybe that these libs were never included in qt 4.8.5? Seems to be compile fine on windows 8.1 and ubuntu 12.04 :)